# C# security of resource files

Tags: c#, security, embedded-resource

I was looking for this an hour, but I didn't find anything.
I read a tutorial about **resource files** and I decided to try them.
I was surprised when I saw the output, because the resource files were changed in DLLs and weren't in the .exe file.

My question are:

- How are these files safe?
- What is safe to store in them?

Comment: How safe is anything you store on a computer?

Comment: 'Is it safe'  is meaningless unless you add 'Is it safe from xxxx'.

Comment: Resource files were meant to store resources (what a surprise), and not sensitive information, like user data or passwords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [first Google hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx) on "resource files security site:msdn.microsoft.com" states:

> **Caution**
>
> Do not use resource files to store passwords, security-sensitive information, or private data.

They don't say that for no reason: a resource file is by default not encrypted or obfuscated, so anyone with any program like a resource editor, msil.exe, or JustDecompile can see the contents of your resource file.

You can apply encryption using some sort of key, but then again you'd have to store the key somewhere to decrypt the resources. This key itself is then subject to the same problems: where do you securely store that, so an attacker can't use it to decrypt your resources?

It's nigh impossible if you have to distribute your program, so simply look for an alternate solution. Perhaps explaining what exactly you're trying to do helps towards a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you fore your answer. Mainly I wont to use it for language mutations, but I wonted know if it's possible to use it for anything else than "resources" (ex. last 10 scores or list of things to do).
This is what I was searching for.

Comment: @user1488122 no, a resource file can't (easily) be changed, so it's not suitable for something like a high score list. Write the scores to a text file, apply encryption if you don't want the users to mess with it, but then you're back to square one: a user can decompile your program to find the encryption key. You can make it hard to alter it, but not impossible.

Comment: You can store your key in services like Azure KeyVault.

Comment: @Adam that didn't exist ten years ago when I wrote that answer. The context here is to deliver something to consumers' machines and keep it there securely. You can't. If you use a KeyVault service, where are you going to store the API keys that let you read from it, and how will you prevent the user from reading those?

Comment: It's all written in MS Docs - you need to register your app with a certificate and then the security is mostly based on that certificate. This is one possibility.

Comment: @Adam got a link for me? My point is: if you deliver an executable or assembly to consumers with a key in it, consumers _will_ get the key out of it. Either through MITM when it authenticates against the resource that requires the key (e.g. Fiddler, though certificate pinning may mitigate that), DLL injection, disassembly, using a debugger or just dumping the memory. You comment on a ten year old answer to say "X can do it" without explaining how, so please elaborate. :)

Comment: Check it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Adam that is for hosting in ASP.NET on Azure. The context here is whether you can keep credentials secure while deploying them on an end user's device using resource files. Nothing of what you've claimed proves that to be possible, because it isn't.

Comment: Read again ;) You don't have to keep it on Azure. You just have to keep your certificate there. From my testing - it can be even self hosted for development. It can be also Let's Encrypt (I think you can sign your exe with Let's Encrypt, but this rather has no sense).

Comment: @Adam despite your insistence that I should keep reading, I cannot find what you claim. Can you provide a direct link, heading or quote that explains how I can deliver an executable to end-users that will obtain authentication credentials from elsewhere while keeping those credentials safe from the (malicious) user of said executable, who is running it on their own machine?

Comment: Use service like Azure KeyVault. Using KV you keep only your KeyVaultName, AADDirectoryId and ApplicationId which are NOT secrets. .NET configuration mechanism can then provide you your KeyVault data in some encrypted way. Of course user can always search memory of your process, but there is nothing about that you can do.